# How do I make a driver function when the function to be tested requires user input?

Tags: c++, project

I'm working on a project for my college introduction to cs class where we have to code a "casino" of sorts. One of the requirements is that the user can select a "test case" function, that, when selected, tests all of our functions. The problem is, how do I test-run functions which require a lot of user input and employ a lot of random numbers as well?

I've tried looking into how to have the computer input instead of the user, but I havent found anything conclusive. Also, when providing answers, keep in mind this is an introductory class, and so my code will neither be clean nor efficient, but it is what I have learned.

Sample game of high/low for "casino":

```cpp
void highLowGame(int &currentBalance)
{
  int betAmount;
  int baseNum;
  int secondNum;
  char hOrL;
  char continueYOrN;

  do
  {
    cout << "Your current balance is $" << currentBalance << "\nHow much would you like to bet?\n";
    cin >> betAmount;

    betAmount = correctIntInput(betAmount);
    betAmount = validBet(currentBalance, betAmount);
    baseNum = randomWithMax(9) + 1;

    cout << "The first number is " << baseNum << "\nDo you bet (h)igh, or (l)ow?\n";
    cin >> hOrL;
    hOrL = correctCharInput(hOrL);

    while (!(hOrL == 'l' || hOrL == 'L' || hOrL == 'h' || hOrL == 'H'))
    {
      cout << "Invalid input, please enter 'H' or 'L'\n";
      cin >> hOrL;
    }

    secondNum = randomWithMax(9) + 1;
    cout << "The second number is " << secondNum << "\n";

    if ((((hOrL == 'l') || (hOrL == 'L')) && (secondNum < baseNum)) || (((hOrL == 'h') || (hOrL == 'H')) && (secondNum > baseNum)))
    {
      cout << "Congratulations, you won your bet!\n";
      updateBalance(currentBalance, 1, betAmount, true);
      cout << "Your new balance is " << currentBalance << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Looks like you lost your bet!\n";
      updateBalance(currentBalance, 1, betAmount, false);
      cout << "Your new balance is " << currentBalance << "\n";
    }

    if (currentBalance <= 0)
    {
      cout << "Uh oh, you are bankrupt!\n";
      break;
    }

    cout << "Would you like to play again?\n";
    cin >> continueYOrN;
    continueYOrN = correctCharInput(continueYOrN);

    while (continueYOrN != 'n' && continueYOrN != 'N' && continueYOrN != 'y' && continueYOrN != 'Y')
    {
      cout << "Invalid input, please enter a new input:\n";
      cin >> continueYOrN;
      continueYOrN = correctCharInput(continueYOrN);
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
  }while(!(continueYOrN == 'n' || continueYOrN == 'N'));
```

Sample "test" given by professor, which tests a function called updateBalance() which just does the functions listed in the pass/fail conditions:

```cpp
void test()
{
  int sampleBalance = 100;
  int sampleBet = 50;
  int samplePayout = 5;
  bool sampleWin = true;

  cout << "Testing updateBalance() win...";
  updateBalance(sampleBalance, sampleBet, samplePayout, sampleWin);
  if (sampleBalance == sampleBalance + samplePayout * sampleBet)
  {
    cout << "Pass!\n";
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Fail!\n";
  }
}
```

Sorry for the large code block for the highLow game, I wasn't sure what parts I should pull out, if any.
I don't even know what to expect as output (other than pass/fail), as I'm not even sure how to do what the professor is asking.
Again, I'm quite new at this, so my code may be dirty and or inefficient, and I am fine with hat, I just need help on how to complete my assignment.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update your answer to give a few examples of possible input the user could enter? If the input must come from `std::cin`, you can write a `C++` program that prints out random inputs, and then pipe that to your code. (I'd do it in `python`, personally.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea how to make a program that prints random inputs. I've only really been doing this for 7 weeks, so the most advanced thing I know how to do is arrays, and even then only basic level stuff. As for why I used c++, its required by the course. And for sample input, it really depends on what point of the code. For example, they can enter y or n when asked if they want to continue, but when asked how much they want to bet they need to enter a number that is greater than zero but less than their current balance

Comment: Are you testing the functions that require user input, or are you only testing the ones that do math behind the scenes?

Comment: I finished the part that  tests the math functions, but based on the directions it looks like the professor wants us to test the ones with user input as well.

Comment: Probably best to confirm that with your professor then - and further, it could also be helpful to confirm how many tests you need to run. If they are only expecting one, you could probably do it by hand; regardless, if your professor knows more than we do, they're the one to ask!

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that the professors example function requires no user input, and has no random elements.

If I were going to write tests for this, I'd break up my methods into smaller methods. Then I'd test the methods that have no user input, and no random elements.

I've noticed that you have the method `correctIntInput(betAmount)`. That looks like a good candidate for testing. Write a few tests that pass in known good and bad values, and then verify that it gives you bad the expected result. Same with `validBet(...)` and  `updateBalance(...)`.

This chuck of code could also be placed into its own function and tested.

```
if ((((hOrL == 'l') || (hOrL == 'L')) && (secondNum < baseNum)) || (((hOrL == 'h') || (hOrL == 'H')) && (secondNum > baseNum)))
{
  cout << "Congratulations, you won your bet!\n";
  updateBalance(currentBalance, 1, betAmount, true);
  cout << "Your new balance is " << currentBalance << "\n";
}
else
{
  cout << "Looks like you lost your bet!\n";
  updateBalance(currentBalance, 1, betAmount, false);
  cout << "Your new balance is " << currentBalance << "\n";
}
```

As you do this type of thing more, you'll be a better feel as to how to break up your code, and what type of code is easy to test and what is hard. Eventually you'll get to a place where the stuff that is hard to test is only a tiny portion of your code base, and the rest of it is covered by tests.